# Why is past simple used here?

Tags: grammar, tenses

This is a famous quote that I first encountered while watching the movie "The Usual Suspects":

"The greatest trick the Devil ever pulled was convincing the world he didn't exist."

And now I am wondering, why is past simple used here? I mean, I have no justification for whether to use past simple or present perfect. Using present perfect seems reasonable, since the action happened at a non-specific time in the past. The quote would be:

"The greatest trick the Devil has ever pulled was convincing the world he didn't exist."

Am I correct?